# Get webview cursor position

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext, selection, text-cursor

I am using `WebView` as rich text editor from a library to insert a string into the cursor's current position.

In `EditText` I am able to know cursor current position using `getSelectionStart` and `getSelectionEnd`, but in `WebView` there is no such method.

How to get cursor current location and insert string to that location ?